# jquery advanced selector construction

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am new to using jquery, and I need a help with advanced jquery selectors.

i need to select all h2, h3 and span tags, but not those that are descendants of div that are have class **foo**. best what i fugured out is this:

```
$("h2, h3, span").not("div.foo h2, div.foo h3, div.foo span")
```

i guess that i dont need to say that i dont like it. i guess i could also use

```
$("h2, h3, span").not("div.foo *")
```

but that limits my possibilities to manipulate with it, for example, allowing h3 to be selected even in said divs while h2 still not.

I would rather like to know what is and advanced way (if there is some) of combining selectors.

Comment: I actually don't see a problem doing it like this. You could however give the headings you like to select a certain class (like opt-in instead of opt-out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why shouldn't we use this.? `$("div:not(.foo),div:not(:has(.foo))").find("h2,h3,span")`

What about using `.filter()` with callback at this context?

```
$("h2, h3, span").filter(function(){
  return $(this).parents('.foo').length == 0;
});
```

Comment: that would not work. if you have <div><div class="foo"><h2> then first div would be selected by first part of selector, second not indeed, but h2 would still be found in first div. 
same for vice versa, eg. <div class="foo"><div><h2>

Comment: @LukášRutar Oh.. Then we need to have a look at the mysterious DOM structure that you have, before answering in a precise way.

Comment: i dont want my sturcture specific solution. i need general solution to "select all h2, h3 and span tags, but not those that are descendants of div.foo"